# Terminology for how "grouped" an ordered data set is

Tags: terminology

Apologies in advance for poor terminology / description below; I'm trying my best but I do not know the correct wording.

Let's say a "sample" is some fixed number $n$ of boolean values (I'll use 1=true, 0=false):

```
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

Now I have a list of samples all of size $n$, and the order of items in the list is significant. So, for example, list A:

```
Sample 1:  0 1 1
Sample 2:  1 0 0
Sample 3:  0 0 1
Sample 4:  0 1 0
Sample 5:  1 0 1
Sample 6:  0 1 0
Sample 7:  1 0 0
```

Consider also this list, which is the same data as above but in a different order, call it list B:

```
Sample 1:  1 0 0
Sample 2:  1 0 0
Sample 3:  1 0 1
Sample 4:  0 0 1
Sample 5:  0 1 1
Sample 6:  0 1 0
Sample 7:  0 1 0
```

Both list A and list B have the same sets of samples, but the order of the samples in list B minimizes "vertical gaps" of 1's ("true" items).

My question is: Is there a word that expresses some quantification of how "grouped" individual elements across samples are for a given order of the list? Sorry if that was vague, but what I mean is, is there some word where I can say "List B has a higher/lower ______ than list A"?

Another way to state my question is, if I was given list A, and wanted to reorder it to get list B, I'm looking for a word that fits "Reordering list A such that the ______ is minimized/maximized gives list B."

From my understanding, the concept is not "entropy", as entropy is [independent of order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Symmetry), and so the entropy of list A and list B is the same (if a given "sample" is a value of the variable that entropy is being calculated of). Unless there is some other type of entropy or entropy-like concept that is order-dependent (so XXXXYYYY has less of it than XYXYXYXY).

I'm looking for an actual statistics word / concept that I can search for (because I need to analyze this quality of various lists, somehow), not just descriptive English words like "List B is *nicer looking* than list A". I'm trying to research algorithms to quantify this but I am frustrated because I do not know what to Google for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a similarity metric, $f$, between two rows. For each consecutive pairs of rows compute $f(row_i, row_j)$. Define an "ideal ordering" to be any member of the permutation of the list that minimizes the sum over $f$.

A reasonable starting point for $f$ is would be the sum of the squared mismatched positions, $$||row_i - row_j||^2 $$

$$Table_1=[3^2, 2^2, 2^2, 3^2, 3^2, 2^2]=39$$
$$Table_2=[0^2, 1^2, 1^2, 1^2, 1^2, 0^2]=4$$

Comment: If my lists contain *every* sample in the population, is it reasonable to let $p(x)$ be the observed relative frequency of $x$, and then $p(x,y)=p(x)p(y)$?

Comment: ... I guess not; because then $I(X,Y)$ would always be 0.

Comment: @Jason C I think I understand your problem better. See my edits.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the entropy of a random variable describing 3 successive coin tosses. I am not sure in what context nicer is relevant but the link below should help

"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)

Comment: Thanks; although I'm not sure this is quite the right concept. Entropy, at least Shannon entropy, is [symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Symmetry) - independent of order; that is XYXYXYXY has the same entropy as XXXXYYYY. So both my list A and list B would have the same entropy by this model.

Comment: (I am currently looking through Google results for "asymmetric entropy" although I haven't hit gold there yet.)

Comment: ohh!! so both samples are just rearrangements?? I thought only for illustrations you used re-arrangements

Comment: Yes, sorry for explaining poorly. I'm trying to quantify this quality for two lists of the same set of samples that differ only in order - i.e. for different permutations of the same sample set.